# Is there a way to optimize the comparison of a matrix with a set of samples?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization

This is the case of a 3D camera streaming a depth map of a scene. The resolution of the camera is known and equal to (w, h) which is set to (3, 2) for this example.

I try to compare each new frame with a bag of samples. Each pixel has the same number of samples to be compared with which is known and equal to 4 for this example. The bag of samples has the following shape (w, h, nb_sample) which is equal to (3, 2, 4) for this example.

I loop from 0 to nb_sample to compare the new frame with the samples. If the difference is higher than a threshold R, a counter is incremented.

The question is: Is there a way to optimize the loop?

```
import numpy as np

w = 3
h = 2
nb_sample = 4
R = 0.5

new_matrix = np.random.rand(w,h)

sample = np.random.rand(w, h, nb_sample)

count = np.zeros((w,h))

for index in range(0, nb_sample):
    distance = np.abs(new_matrix - sample[:, :, index])
    count[distance < R] += 1

print(count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this two line solution:

```
distance = np.abs(sample - new_matrix[:,:,np.newaxis])
np.sum(distance < R, axis = -1)
```

**Explanation**:

By adding a dimension to `new_matrix` with `np.newaxis` numpy can calculate the difference for each matrix in `sample` using the `-` operation.

Then `distance < R` is calculated like in your code. `True` and `False` are represented as `1` and `0` in python, which is why they can then simply be added together along the right axis.